# How to show attachments as icons / Disable inline preview on Catalina

Tags: mail.app, catalina, preview

As mentioned in the topic want to get rid of that confusing inline preview. I found

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

However this only applies for the send-mail-window, not the regular mail view of received mail. How would I change this?